# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Log4j doesn't work even with jar files

Tags: java, log4j

I've added `log4j-api-2.13.0.jar:log4j-core-2.13.0.jar` to CLASSPATH but still I get the following error. Any idea how to resolve the error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
        at demo.selenium.IBanTest.<clinit>(IBanTest.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

ENV:

```
CLASSPATH=".:selenium-chrome-driver-3.12.0.jar:selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar:guava-13.0.1.jar:junit4.jar:log4j-api-2.13.0.jar:log4j-core-2.13.0.jar"
```

BASH:

```
java demo.selenium.IBanTest
```

Comment: After every change in dependencies or jars clean and rebuild project.

Comment: That is Linux syntax.  Are you on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I also had to include `log4j2-2.3.jar`.

```
log4j-core-2.14.1.jar
log4j2-2.3.jar
log4j-api-2.14.1.jar
```

CLASSPATH for example would be like:

```
CLASSPATH = ".:/home/user/:selenium-chrome-driver-3.12.0.jar:selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar:guava-13.0.1.jar:junit4.jar:log4j-core-2.14.1.jar:log4j2-2.3.jar:log4j-api-2.14.1.jar"
```

And run the program in directory target/classes/:

```
java demo.selenium.IBanTest
```